# Excel 2010: How to color the area between charts?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, charts

I asked this question already on stackoverflow but it hasn't been answered yet. Instead I was advised to try it here, so here I go :)

So there's that simple XY-Line-Chart in Excel (2010). It is surrounded by two other graphs which are parallel but offset by the same factor in both the positive and negative direction - something like this:

---------------- (positively offset parallel graph)

---------------- (main graph)

---------------- (negatively offset parallel graph)

Now I want to color the space between the main graph and the offset ones. Is it possible with VBA or is there a solution for Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you need:

http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=590

It uses the difference between the lines to fill the required regions of the plot.